# I can't solve $x-2<\frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, factoring, fractions

We have to solve this inequation.

$x-2<\frac{1}{x-1}$.

So we try $(x-1)(x-2)<1$ what's wrong ?

Please, give me a hint.

Comment: If you multiply both sides of an inequality by, say, $x-1$, you have to check that it is positive.  If it is negative, the inequality changes direction.

Comment: You can't multiply by $x-1$, but you can multiply by $(x-1)^2$

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin: That's not really advisable, though, because then you end up with a _cubic_ equation to solve.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but we'll know that one of the roots is $1$, so solving a cubic equation isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's wrong because $x-1$ can be negative.

We need
$$x-2-\frac{1}{x-1}<0$$ or
$$\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x-1}<0$$ or
$$\frac{\left(x-\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)}{x-1}<0,$$
which gives the answer.

I got $$\left(-\infty,\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)\cup\left(1,\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x-2<\frac { 1 }{ x-1 } \\ x-2-\frac { 1 }{ x-1 } <0\\ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-3x+1 }{ x-1 } <0\\ \frac { \left( x-\frac { 3-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \left( x-\frac { 3+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \left( x-1 \right)  }{ { \left( x-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } <0\\ \left( x-\frac { 3-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \left( x-\frac { 3+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \left( x-1 \right) <0\\ x\in \left( -\infty ,\frac { 3-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \cup \left( 1,\frac { 3+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }  \right) \\ $$

Answer (score 0):

hint: solve 
$$x^2-3x+2<1 , \hspace{10pt}  x>1 $$ 
$$x^2-3x+1<0 , \hspace{10pt}  x>1 $$

and

$$x^2-3x+2>1 , \hspace{10pt}  x>1 $$ 
$$x^2-3x+1>0 , \hspace{10pt}  x<1 $$

Answer (score 0):

If you have $x<y$ and multiply it by positive number $a$, then it is still true that $ax < ay$. If you multiply it by negative number $b$, then the inequality changes direction, so $bx > by$ is true instead.

For example, we know that $2<3$ and if we multiply it by $2$, we get $4<6$, which is still true, but if we multiply it by $-2$, it is not true that $-4<-6$, but on the contrary, $-4>-6$.

What does it have to do with solving inequalities?

You have $$x-2 < \frac 1{x-1}$$ and want to multiplity it by $x-1$. So, what is true: $(x-2)(x-1)<1$ or $(x-2)(x-1)>1$? According to the above discussion, if $x-1>0$, the former is true, and if $x-1<0$ the latter is true. But, the problem is that we don't know whether $x-1$ is positive or negative, so we would entangle ourselves into some casework.

However, there is a common trick to avoid this, multiply by $(x-1)^2$ instead of $x-1$! We do know that $(x-1)^2>0$, so the inequality becomes $$(x-2)(x-1)^2<x-1.$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: Why doesn't the LHS become $(x-2)(x-1)^2$?

Comment: @Henning Makholm, it does, of course, thank you for noticing :)

Answer (score 0):

$x-1<1/(x-1) +1;$

Set $a:= x-1$, $a \not =0$.

$a < 1/a +1;$

1) Let $a >0$; then

$a^2-a -1 <0.$

$(a-1/2)^2 \lt 5/4;$

$|a-1/2| \lt (1/2)√5;$

We get for $a >0$: $a < 1/2 +(1/2)√5$.;

2) $a < 0$:

$a^2-a-1 >0;$

$(a-1/2)^2 >5/4.$

$|a-1/2| >(1/2)√5$;

We get for a <0: $1/2-a >(1/2)√5$, or

$a < 1/2-(1/2)√5$.

Combining:

$a \in (-\infty, \dfrac{1-√5}{2})\cup (0,\dfrac{1+√5}{2}).$

Now revert to $x$.